# How can I use a '>' or '<' in the when clause of a control file?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'Sample2.dat'
APPEND INTO TABLE EMP_LEAVE
WHEN REQUEST_DATE > SYSDATE  --The problem lies here
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
(REQUEST_NO,
EMPNO,
REQUEST_DATE    DATE    "DD-MM-YYYY",
START_DATE  DATE    "DD-MM-YYYY",
END_DATE        DATE    "DD-MM-YYYY",
REASON,
LEAVE_TYPE,
NO_OF_DAYS,
APPROVAL
)
```

I'm trying to insert only those rows where the REQUEST_DATE is higher than the current date. Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't directly from SQL*Loader.

`WHEN` clause, which is used to conditionally load records, accepts only "equal" or "not equal" operators, i.e. `=`, `<>` or `!=`, i.e. you can't use "greater than" `>` and similar.

For more info, see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-805F7263-D384-4C5D-BADD-2424324F3B90.htm#SUTIL1199):

> A field condition is a statement about a field in a logical record
> that evaluates as true or false. **It is used in the WHEN**, NULLIF,
> and DEFAULTIF clauses.
>
> (...)
>
> operator: A comparison operator for either **equal** or **not equal**.

So, what to do?

- load data into a temporary table and then extract rows you want
- instead of SQL*Loader, use **external tables** feature which lets you write a query against it (i.e. you're directly accessing the file as if it were an "ordinary" table, so you can use any `WHERE` clause you want, including `where request_date > sysdate`)